# Why doesn't the object show up in the scene?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, papervision3d

I am using the following code to load .md2 model in a scene using Papervision3D 2.1.932.

```
_md2.load(MD2_FILE ,new BitmapFileMaterial("./assets/dragon.png"));
scene.addChild(_md2);
```

By looking at the trace log, the texture is successfully loaded and so is the mesh.

```
INFO: BitmapFileMaterial: Loading bitmap from ./assets/dragon.png 
INFO: Parsed MD2: assets/dragon.md2
 vertices:294
 texture vertices:262
 faces:582
 frames: 200
```

I can't understand why the object isn't visible in the scene.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the camera is facing the model.
Check the scale by comparing with other md2 models that showup with no problem.